# JavaScript function in function, returning and accessing a value

Tags: javascript, function

Im totally new to JavaScript but my friend asked me for help. Im wondering if something like this would be possible in JS?

If the value of project is "garden"

I should get couple values for example for a name:

Garden Project

I tried that:

```
var myProject="garden";
ProjectNew.detectTemplate(myProject).choosenProject.name;
```

Im getting:

```
Unexpected exception 'ReferenceError: ProjectsNew is not defined
```

But it doesn't work. Is it possible what I described and would like to do in JS?

```
var ProjectNew = function() {

   function detectTemplate(project) {

      if (project=='garden'){
        var choosenProject = {
          name: "Garden Project",
          description: "sample description'",
          ansprechpartner: "Greg",
          branche: "shoping",
          partner: "'Stihl",
          technik: 'lawn mover selling'
          };
          return choosenProject;
       }
       }
        return {
               detectTemplate: detectTemplate
      }

}();
```

Comment: Don't know what the overall objective is, but this sure seems like a complicated way to associate a string with an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code mostly works. There are just two parts you missed:

1. Since you are defining `ProjectNew` using an assignment statement, you need to assign it before you try to use it. The error you are seeing means that it does not yet have a value when you are attempting to use it (or it is not within the scope where you are trying to use it).
2. `detectTemplate()` returns the `choosenProject` itself, not an object with a property named `choosenProject`, so you need to remove that portion from your series of property accesses.

Working code:

```js
var ProjectNew = function() {
  function detectTemplate(project) {

    if (project == 'garden') {
      var choosenProject = {
        name: "Garden Project",
        description: "sample description'",
        ansprechpartner: "Greg",
        branche: "shoping",
        partner: "'Stihl",
        technik: 'lawn mover selling'
      };
      return choosenProject;
    }
  }
  return {
    detectTemplate: detectTemplate
  }

}();
var myProject = "garden";
console.log(ProjectNew.detectTemplate(myProject).name);
```